# Error al clasificar texto en diferentes .txt

Tags: python

Estaba intentando automatizar la clasificación de pequeñas lineas de texto con un limitado conocimiento sobre Python que alguna vez aprendí hace unos años. Después de renegar un poco con el abrir, cerrar, leer y escribir supuse que ya debería poder intentar hacer una versión simplificada. Construir un .txt con diferentes cosas e intente clasificarlas por pronombre. Me quedo algo como esto.

```
RF = open('Tc.txt', 'r')
WF1 = open('C1.txt', 'a')
WF2 = open('C2.txt', 'a')
List = []
List = RF.readlines()
for i in List:
    if "El " or " el " in i:
        WF1.write(i)
    elif "La " or " la " in i:
        WF2.write(i)
```

Cuando revise los archivos, todas las palabras estaban en C1.txt. En ese momento me puse a hacer pequeños cambios hasta que decidí transformar el problema en algo un poco mas grafico y que no dependiera de abrir y cerrar archivos. Construí esto.

```
List = ["Las cosas", "Los Cosos"]
G1 = []
G2 = []
for i in List:
    if "El " or " el " in i:
        G1.append(i)
    elif "La " or " la " in i:
        G2.append(i)
print ("Las cosas masculinas son:")
    for i in G1:
        print i
print ("Las cosas femeninas son:")
    for i in G2:
        print i
```

El resuntado fue que todas las palabras estaban clasificadas como masculinas. Y ese fue el punto cuando decidi venir aqui.

Comment: como asi el mismo?, podrias poner cual fue la entra y cual fue la salida?

Comment: ¿Cual es el error? ¿Cual es el resultado correcto?

Comment: Como resalto la respuesta que mas me ayudo?

Comment: Pero su comentario resolvió el problema

Comment: Muchísimas Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El condicional:

```
if "El " or " el " in i:
```

no hace lo que esperas. La forma correcta es escribir varias expresiones de pertenencia que usen `in` y combinar todas ellas con `or`, es decir:

```
if "El " in i or " el " in i:
```

No obstante se puede mejorar para evitar tener que andar comprobando mayúsculas y mínúsculas (y evitar tener que poner espacios) si:

1. Convertimos el texto que hay en `i` en minúsculas con `.lower()`
2. Usamos `.split()` para dividir ese texto en palabras
3. Miramos si `"el"` está en la lista de palabras resultante.

Es decir:

```
if "el" in i.lower().split():
```

### Extra ¿por qué no funcionó la sintaxis original?

El operador `or` tiene menos precedencia que el operador `in`, por lo que tu expresión equivalía a esta otra (pongo paréntesis para que quede más claro el orden de evaluación):

```
if ("El ") or (" el " in i):
```

Es una expresión booleana un poco rara... La parte final está clara: `(" el " in i)` mira si la cadena `" el "` aparece dentro de `i`. Eso producirá un booleano como resultado que será `True` o `False`.

Pero ese booleano se combina mediante `or` con `("El ")`. Para poder hacer esa operación booleana, Python debe asignar un "valor de verdad" a la expresión `"El "`. Eso lo hace usando `bool("El ")`, y sale `True`.

Sale `True` porque toda cadena no vacía, al ser evaluada como booleano, da `True` (sólo daría `False` una cadena vacía).

Así que tu expresión equivale en el fondo a:

```
if True or (" el " in i):
```

Esta expresión será siempre `True` sin que importe el valor de la segunda parte. Por eso todas tus palabras acababan en la primera lista.